# Similarity of particle in a box and free particle

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, wavefunction, boundary-conditions

It can be shown that particle in a box and free particle have [the same energy at certain wavenumbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_in_a_box#/media/File:Confined_particle_dispersion_-_positive.svg) (at an integer multiple of $\pi/L$ , where $L$ is the length of the box)

I am aware that the general wavefunctions of the two particles spoken of are different, but I can't get over the fact that both particles have a $k^2$ dependence on energy.

If we can do the correlation, it seems as if the free particle becomes a particle in a box at these wavenumbers. Can I visualize the free particle becoming a standing wave in such situations? But a length is not defined for the free particle so that wouldn't make sense for such a particle.

Is there any similarity between them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The particle in a box is simply a free particle which lives in a compact interval $[0,L]$ rather than $\mathbb R$, and whose energy eigenstates are chosen to vanish at the endpoints.  In other words, the free-particle energy eigenfunctions$^\dagger$ satisfy $-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\psi''(x) = E\psi(x)$, while the particle-in-a-box energy eigenstates satisfy $-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\psi''(x) = E\psi(x)$ **and** the boundary conditions $\psi(0)=\psi(L)=0$.

Any function on $[0,L]$ can be extended to a function on $\mathbb R$ by copying and pasting it along the whole real line.  From the above argument, it follows that (the extensions of) the particle-in-a-box energy eigenstates are also free particle eigenstates which additionally obey the prescribed conditions at $x=0$ and $x=L$.

---

$^\dagger$The free particle energy "eigenstates" are non-normalizable, but this is somewhat beside the point of this disccusion.

Comment: wouldnt it make so much more sense if physisists called it ' "free" particle in a box'

Comment: @displayjfmrfv That would raise the debate as to whether a particle in a box could meaningfully be said to be free.  I suppose you could say "the *otherwise* free particle in a box" but that's a bit clunky. In any case, this is a good reminder that you shouldn't infer anything technical about a system purely from the non-technical name we use to refer to it.